# Do we get a section on a ringed space $\mathcal{A}$ by mapping each element $x$ to the multiplicative unit element $1_x$ of $\mathcal{A}_x$?

Tags: sheaf-theory, ringed-spaces

Suppose $(X, \mathcal{A})$ is a ringed space (where $\mathcal{A}$ is assumed to be a sheaf of unital, commutative rings over $X$) and consider the map
\begin{eqnarray}
\psi \colon X \to \mathcal{A} \qquad X \ni x \mapsto 1_x \in \mathcal{A}_x
\end{eqnarray}

> Is it true that this map must always be continuous, i.e. that $\psi$ is a section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element $1_x\in\mathcal{A}_x$ is just the image of the unit $1\in\mathcal{A}(X)$ under the restriction map $\mathcal{A}(X)\to\mathcal{A}_x$.  So, your map is continuous, since it corresponds to the section $1\in\mathcal{A}(X)$.

Comment: I see that there has to exist a unit $1 \in \mathcal{A}(X)$. This may be a very stupid question, but how do you deduce that $1(x) = 1_x$ for all $x \in X$?

Comment: Because it is a sheaf of unital rings, meaning that the restriction maps are unital ring homomorphisms.

Comment: True, thank you! :)